# $ionicPlatform ready necessary to call every time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I realise that `$ionicPlatform.ready` function has been executed by default in `app.js` file generated by ionic (under module.run)

My question is:
Is it still necessary to explicitly initiate `$ionicPlatform.ready` in controller that use cordova plugin that requires `ondeviceready`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it still necessary to explicitly initiate $ionicPlatform.ready in
>   controller that use cordova plugin that requires ondeviceready

As you know `app.js` a.e. `run` method is called 1st in lifecycle of your app.

However you can implement `$ionicPlatform.ready` in multiple controllers as well.

`ondeviceready` event has the same behavior and Ionic uses it and gives you API  `$ionicPlatform.ready` instead.  Its a good practice to use it because Ionic after gets callback from 
`document.addEventListener("deviceready", onPlatformReady, false);` does other good stuff that we use like toolbar styling, keyboard, other Ionic plugins and so on

Reference:

```
/**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name ionic.Platform#ready
     * @description
     * Trigger a callback once the device is ready, or immediately
     * if the device is already ready. This method can be run from
     * anywhere and does not need to be wrapped by any additonal methods.
     * When the app is within a WebView (Cordova), it'll fire
     * the callback once the device is ready. If the app is within
     * a web browser, it'll fire the callback after `window.load`.
     * Please remember that Cordova features (Camera, FileSystem, etc) still
     * will not work in a web browser.
     * @param {function} callback The function to call.
     */
    ready: function(cb) {
      // run through tasks to complete now that the device is ready
      if (self.isReady) {
        cb();
      } else {
        // the platform isn't ready yet, add it to this array
        // which will be called once the platform is ready
        readyCallbacks.push(cb);
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do your checks on a splash/startup screen and not proceed to the rest of the app (views with controllers) until the device is ready. Then you wouldn't need to explicitly check all the time in various controllers or services that are called after, once you've gone past that first check.